# Swipe TextView to change page (open specific detail view)

Tags: android, swipe

So I'm making sort of a Master-Detail type app where the user is presented a list of data. Each list row has a matching detail view.

Now I know how to set it to open the corresponding detail view when the user presses a list item. However I am wondering how to set it up so that swiping a list item slides open the corresponding view (with the proper ViewPager-esque animation ofcourse).

As an example I can think of the snapchat app, swipe a name and you open the chat/history page for that contact.